# why angular2 component constructor parameters must be provided

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, angular-components

I am brand new to Angular. When I am doing the Heros tutorial, I noticed type of component constructor parameters must be a dependency. In other words, I must include it in providers array.

For example:

```
import { SomeServiceClass } from '...';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(input1: SomeServiceClass) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This code is not going to work unless I include SomeServiceClass in providers array. I tried `input1: string`. It doesn't work neither! I believe it is totally valid typescript code. The problem must be the way angular2 instantiates the component classes.

**Question 1**: How are component classed actually instantiated by Angular?

And, since I never instantiate service class, I can't imagine which service class instance is passed to component constructor.

**Question 2**: Does angular create one instance of service to be used by every component or it generates one instance for each component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This code is not going to work unless I include SomeServiceClass in providers array. I tried input1: string. It doesn't work neither! I believe it is totally valid typescript code. The problem must be the way angular2 instantiates the component classes.

The reason you need to add `SomeServiceClass` to a `providers` array of some`ngModule` is simple. Angular *chose* not to perform any dependency analysis based on code structure. They could have used the ES Module import in the injecting component to resolve the dependency and auto register it.

As evidence, [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) does exactly that.

In other words, in Aurelia, the following is sufficient to inject and use a dependency

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {SomeServiceClass} from '...';

@autoinject export class MyComponent {
  constructor(input1: SomeServiceClass) {}
}
```

And it works.

> How are component classed actually instantiated by Angular?
>
> And, since I never instantiate service class, I can't imagine which service class instance is passed to component constructor.

A class in JavaScript is really a constructor function, and a constructor function is really a glorified factory function, and a factory function is really a glorified function.

What does that mean?

It means that Angular (and most DI frameworks) simply create an instance of the service when it is first requested by calling the provided class with `new`.

A simplified version of such code might look like

```
function instantiateComponent<T>(Component: new (...args: any[]) => T) {
  const requiredDependencies = resolveDependencies(Component);

  return new Component(...requiredDependencies);
}

function resolveDependencies(Dep: new (...args: any[]) => any): object[] {
  const requiredDependencies = metaDataUtils.getDependencies(Dep);
  
  return requiredDependencies.map(Dep => {
     const alreadyCreatedDependency = injectorCache.find(dep => dep instanceof Dep);
     
     if(alreadyCreatedDependency !== undefined) {
       return alreadyCreatedDependency;
     }
     else {
       const requiredDependencies = metaDataUtils.getDependencies(Dep);
       
       // resolution is recursive
       const newDependency = new Dep(...requiredDependencies.map(resolveDependencies));

       injectorCache.push(newDependency);

       return newDependency;
     }
  });
}
```

> Does angular create one instance of service to be used by every component or it generates one instance for each component?

This one is tricky, by default only one instance is created per application.

This is an application level singleton and all components requesting it receive the same instance.

However, there are different implicit and explicit behaviors in Angular as well.

If a lazily loaded `ngModule` lists the same service in its `providers` array, a second instance will be created and that instance will be shared by children of the lazily loaded module. That is actually an over simplification but it is already confusing and, given that whether or not a module is loaded lazily is determined by its consumers, it can lead to serious and subtle bugs.

Finally, a component may explicitly declare its own `providers` in the `@Component` metadata. Any component doing so have will have a new instance of the service created and shared by all instances of that component.

**Note:** Just to be specific when you say

> I noticed type of component constructor parameters must be a dependency.

you are not strictly correct. Dependencies are not *types*, they are *values*. TypeScript types are completely erased at compile time and what actually gets injected are values. A class is a value

```
class C {}
```

but TypeScript also infers the existence of some types from its declaration. But what is injected is the value `C`, not the type `C`.

Comment: Excellent answer! It also makes me thinking about how is an angular application be initialized. Now I only know modules, services and components. Could you explain a little bit about the running order of them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean eager vs lazy?

Comment: Since angular has so many components (not mean Angular Component), there must be a specific order to run those parts of code. Fore example, it could run a Service at first to create a dependency and then run Component  to use the Service. Or it could run Component at first and run Service when the Service is required. These are two scenarios what I mentioned as running order. Does it make sense?

Comment: Sort of. Each `injector` creates services as they are needed to instantiate dependent components/routes/services. So a dependency is initialized when it is first needed and then cached.

Comment: @zhangjinzhou does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, partly. There are other components like Module and Routing. I wanted to know the whole flow of an angular application. Maybe this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @zhangjinzhou not so much too broad but it's not what you asked and it's a lot more too explain and frankly I don't know all the details

Comment: You are right it is totally not related to this question. I found some other materials. Thank you Aluan!